# How Can get the interface list in C++ in linux ?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I want to get my internet interface list in C++ in linux because my program need to down Or up the link but i dont know how get the interface to modifi it.

Answer (score 1):

The system call you are looking for is [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).  There is a brief example program on the man page.

Within the `ifaddrs` there is a bit flag field `ifa_flags` with which you can test whether the interface is up or down.

Comment: @mr duck tnx. but i need show the all interface name and up or down them Tandem . My project is load balancing in network like zen balancer Or microtik load balancer. i write the first part of project (ping) and now i need to run the ping in all link to show that wich link is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Read from /proc/net/dev 
Full description in `man proc`:

```
       /proc/net/dev
              The  dev  pseudo-file contains network device status information.  This gives the number of received and sent packets,
              the number of errors and collisions and other basic statistics.  These are used by the ifconfig(8) program  to  report
              device status.  The format is:

 Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
  face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
     lo: 2776770   11307    0    0    0     0          0         0  2776770   11307    0    0    0     0       0          0
   eth0: 1215645    2751    0    0    0     0          0         0  1782404    4324    0    0    0   427       0          0
   ppp0: 1622270    5552    1    0    0     0          0         0   354130    5669    0    0    0     0       0          0
   tap0:    7714      81    0    0    0     0          0         0     7714      81    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

This is a text file, each interface is a line... should be easy.

For example (no error checking... just printing the interface names)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::ifstream in("/proc/net/dev");

   int c=0;
   std::string line;
   for(; std::getline( in, line ); c++)
   {
       if(c<2) continue; // skip header
       std::size_t start=line.find_first_not_of(" "); // skip leading spaces
       std::size_t end=line.find_first_of(":",start); // look for the ":"
       std::cout << line.substr(start,end-start) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: tnx but i need the pseudo code in c++ to fetch them and show them in terminal.

Comment: @Mehdi added a sample program.